# Select the latest N items sorted in oldest to newer

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to select the latest messages by date of creation with the following entity.

```
type Message struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID `gorm:"primaryKey;type:uuid;not null" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"createdAt"`
    Content   string    `json:"content"`
    Room      *Room     `json:"room,omitempty"`
    RoomID    uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;not null" json:"-"`
    User      *User     `json:"author,omitempty"`
    UserID    uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;not null" json:"-"`
}
```

I've come up with the following query:

```
var messages []entity.Message

// get latest 10 items 
// newest by date will be at the top
if err := r.db.
    Where(&entity.Message{RoomID: room.ID}).
    Order("created_at DESC").
    Limit(10).
    Preload("User").
    Find(&messages).Error; err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

We retrieve the latest 10 messages in descending order by creation date. The problem is that I need to reverse the order after that.

How can we reorder the result ascendingly? (last message should be at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a subquery is nice, but what about simply reversing the slice after you retrieve it?

```golang
for i, j := 0, len(messages)-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    messages[i], messages[j] = messages[j], messages[i]
}
```

Comment: Yeah, your approach seems great to me as well! We could reverse it at a database / server / frontend level, and as far as i am aware, there are many hacks too. I was just wondering which could be the easiest and less painful way.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
if err := r.db.
    Debug().
    Table("(?) as m", r.db.Model(&entity.Message{}).Where(&entity.Message{RoomID: room.ID}).Order("created_at DESC").Limit(20)).
    Order("created_at ASC").
    Preload("User").
    Find(&messages).Error; err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Produces:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."room_id" = '1cf10408-f2b5-4607-8b86-4c0a16ae1fe3' ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 20) as m ORDER BY created_at ASC
```